# MSP430 register argument syntax

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, msp430

I am analyzing an MSP430 program. I am using a tutorial to learn: https://microcorruption.com/cpu/debugger, I came upon this section:

```
4482:  ff40 7e00 0000 mov.b #0x7e, 0x0(r15)
```

I know that it is moving 7e into the r15 register but I do not understand what the 0x0 in front of the register argument is for.

There are also more instructions that follow that example.

```
4488:  ff40 6100 0100 mov.b #0x61, 0x1(r15)
448e:  ff40 4800 0200 mov.b #0x48, 0x2(r15)
4494:  ff40 2f00 0300 mov.b #0x2f, 0x3(r15)
449a:  ff40 3400 0400 mov.b #0x34, 0x4(r15)
44a0:  ff40 6b00 0500 mov.b #0x6b, 0x5(r15)
```

etc.

I also do not know what the ff40 7e00 0000 is.

Comment: It is a displacement value. It is added to the register and that becomes the memory address

Comment: Showing machine-code hex dumps as pairs of bytes is very weird.  Are you sure this is x86 at all?  That's not AT&T or Intel syntax.  AT&T would be `movb $0x61, 0x1(%r15)`.

Comment: **That's definitely *not* x86 machine code**.  `mov r/m8, imm8` has opcode C6, and would start with a REX prefix to use `r15` in the addressing mode.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I'm almost certain that the website's debugger uses a spinoff of x86 that's similar to AT&T syntax. But I'm not sure as to search its documentation.

Comment: @Michael Petch By displacement value, do you mean it splits the register into segments and stores the data in each segment? Also, how will using only the register as an argument without the displacement value affect already stored data in registers that used displacement values?

Comment: a register in parentheses means that the operation involves a memory operand. R15 contains an address to a memory location. The number outside the parentheses is added to R15 and the result of that becomes the memory location that the `mov` operation uses as the destination in this case. It seems to be initializing an array of bytes in memory one byte at a time.

Comment: @JoeGo: The machine code looks like `ff 40 imm16 disp16`, so this is 100% not x86 (or x86-64).  Using R15 means the instruction would have to start with a REX prefix with some bits set, like `41` or something, not `40`.  Byte operand-size `mov` takes an 8-bit immediate, not 16.  And in 64-bit mode (for r15) displacements are 8 or 32 bits.  Opcode byte `ff` is used by multiple instructions which use the `/r` field of the ModR/M byte to differentiate between them.  e.g. `ff /2` is `CALL r/m64`.  [`ff /4` is `jmp r/m64`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/JMP) `ff /0` is `inc r/m32`.

Comment: @JoeGo: But whatever it is, MichaelPetch and PRL are almost certainly correct; this is a very normal feature for asm syntax: the `number(r15)` is an addressing mode that adds a constant to a register value.  And clearly the destination is the 2nd operand, because the first operand is an immediate constant (and thus can't be the destination).

Answer (score 2):

It is not moving the value into the r15 register. The value is being stored in memory. The memory address is the value in the register plus the displacement.

`ff40 7e00 0000` is the encoding of the instruction.